# How to prevent PV input to charge controller if battery breaker trips

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, circuit-breaker

I have a 20amp mppt charge controller ([EP Solar tracer 20a](http://www.epsolarpv.com/en/index.php/Product/pro_content/id/654/am_id/136)).  In the manual it states:

> WARNING: Connect battery terminals to the charge controller BEFORE
>   connecting the solar panel(s) to the charge controller. NEVER connect
>   solar panels to charge controller until the battery is connected.

However, if the breaker (or fuse) between the battery and controller is ever tripped, then it will essentially put the system into this state.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?  Or is this not something that I should really be worried about?

### Update:

Currently the charge controller is connected to the same breaker as the system load (mainly for the convince of being able to disconnect the entire system in 1 switch).  I'm wondering if this might make the scenario above more likely to occur and if I shouldn't run a separate fused line to the battery directly from the charge controller.

Here is a diagram of what my current wiring looks like:

[image]

NOTE: I couldn't find the breaker symbol so I used the switch.  Also the circles are [junction blocks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LM01CNA) that I added for convenience

Comment: Can you show the expected wiring diagram. You should probably add a relay that only connects the solar panel when the battery power is attached to the controller. I am sort of  surprised that is not built in, or included in the recommended wiring diagram.

Comment: @Trevor ya the suggest wiring doesn't saying anything about it.

Comment: Then yes, I'd add a relay downwind of both breakers, maybe solid state to make it fast and low drain on the battery.

Comment: ALternative would be to use a "ganged" breaker so you can not turn off one without the other. But that will not protect you from a battery disconnect, intentional or otherwise.

Comment: Hopefully the controller is robust enough to handle the switching time.

Comment: @Trevor if you want to submit an answer with a little more detail (what wiring would look like and maybe a link to an acceptable relay for my situation) I will upvote and select as answer.

Comment: Ya I am still thinking about what will be on the charger output when the breaker opens. It may not be quite to simple.

Comment: @Trevor reading deep into some solar forms and the reason they say to power on in this sequence is so the charge controller can properly detect the voltage of the system when first powered on.   I THINK that this present is saved into memory.  So I'm not sure if this issue is actually really an issue as long as the initial power up is done correctly.  Still not 100% clear

Comment: Yup there is a vagueness that is disturbing. I gave an answer based on what I think things do.

Comment: Adding to vagueness, my manual also says the controller safely handles battery voltage dropping below 10v (old or fried battery).  When this happens the controller shutsdown and does not turn on until battery returns to 12v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make the battery breaker a double and use one side to feed a relay on the solar lines, maybe solid state to make it fast and low drain on the battery. As shown below. The reason for the ganged breaker is I am not sure what the output of the controller will do when the breaker opens. It may still drive out a high voltage for a while before it dies...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKyoOh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You need to chose a relay that has a coil/activation  voltage that is the same as your battery voltage, and can carry the current expected from the solar panel.

Potential issues: 
1. Hopefully the controller is robust enough to handle the switching time. 2. If the batteries drain too much the relay will drop out.

Alternative would be to "gang" the battery and solar breaker so you can not turn off one without the other. But that will not protect you from a battery disconnect, intentional or otherwise.